# In Spider-Man No Way Home, how did *this villain* come into this universe?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-amazing-spider-man-2, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man No Way Home*, we know that Doctor Strange's spell was botched mid-casting, and that caused everyone who knows that Peter Parker is Spider-Man, to start coming into this Universe.

So, how does Electro come to this Universe, as he never knew that Peter was Spider-Man? This is also confirmed in *No Way Home* when he says, 'You are just a kid... yada yada yada...and I thought you would be black', which means he did not know before!

Comment: Might want to take a peek at [Why was Electro summoned by Dr. Strange's spell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258354/why-was-electro-summoned-by-dr-stranges-spell)

Comment: Hey, thank you! The answer there kind of makes sense!

Comment: Here's a link to the quote from Electro: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10872600/quotes/qt6074025

Comment: @EleventhDoctor: The other quote along those lines: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10872600/quotes/qt6098738

Answer (score 2):

There's a throwaway line in the film about him "absorbing data". Possibly that data included Spider-Man's secret identity.

> "I was whoopin' Spider-Man's ass, he'll tell you! And then, he caused
> an overload. **I was stuck in the grid, absorbing data.** I was about to
> turn into pure energy, and then... oh shit. I was about to die."

That being said, assuming this Electro is the same Electro from *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*, he might have overheard Gwen say Peter's name during their battle.

This would also explain why he didn't know that "Peter" was a white dude if all he knew was his name.